# Additional condition for mysql select query at Jquery Fileuploader

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

Thats the regular function to select the uploaded files

```
protected function set_additional_file_properties($file) {
    parent::set_additional_file_properties($file);


    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {

        $sql = 'SELECT `id`, `type`, `title`, `description` FROM `'
            .$this->options['db_table'].'` WHERE `name`=?';
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bind_param('s', $file->name);
        $query->execute();
        $query->bind_result(
            $id,
            $type,
            $title,
            $description

        );
        while ($query->fetch()) {
            $file->id = $id;
            $file->type = $type;
            $file->title = $title;
            $file->description = $description;

        }
    }
}
```

Now i have an additional field in the database named "userid"(int) and i want to have this field as a condition.

I tried it in all variations but it doesnt work. The where condition is not considered.

The following does not work:

```
 $sql = 'SELECT `id`, `type`, `title`, `description` FROM `'
        .$this->options['db_table'].'` WHERE `name`=? AND userid = '72' ';
```

I also tried to modify in this direction:

```
 $query->bind_param('ss', $file->name,$userid);
```

but nothing helps! Why can't I simply extend the query to a "where" here?

Comment: **Error checking** but if you cannot be bothered, Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: You could try `$query->bind_param('si', $file->name,$userid);` as the datatype you quoted for `userid` was integer